# What's the way to make controller if I want to pass this json code

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'd like to ask you how my rest controller should look like (in springboot) if I want to pass JSON like this

```
user: {email: "c", password: "c", username: "c"}
```

btw JSON which looks like this works fine:

```
{email: "c", password: "c", username: "c"}
```

so I think that it depends on 'user' word in JSON, but the problem is that my front-end sends all requests like this so better way would be to make this operable in backend.

because one my actual which looks like:

```
@PostMapping("/users")
    public void register(@Valid @RequestBody ApplicationUserEntity newUser){

        registerService.registerNewUser(newUser);

    }
```

isn`t acutally working.

Here is the ApplicationUserEntity class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "users")
public class ApplicationUserEntity implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long userId;

    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;

    @JsonProperty("username")
    private String username;

    @JsonProperty("password")
    private String password;

    public ApplicationUserEntity() {
    }

    public ApplicationUserEntity(String email, String username, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the structure of the ApplicationUserEntity object ?

Comment: Are you getting any specific error? It looks like you need to process the request as string before creating the object as it is not the valid json ("user: " and no quotation marks on the keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request body can be the following object:

```
public class Request {
   private ApplicationUserEntity user;
   // getters, setters ...
}
```

Its field is the Entity object that you have created. In this case your controller method would look like this:

```
@PostMapping("/users")
public void register(@Valid @RequestBody Request newUser){

    registerService.registerNewUser(newUser);

}
```

The JSON request in this case would be:

```
{
   user: {
     // fields of the ApplicationUserEntity 
   }
}
```

Note: It is always recommended that you use **DTO objects** as requests and response objects. So in this case you would rather have a DTO object that contains the email, username, password field, and put this object as a field in the Request class.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm still getting nullable values in api

Comment: Do you mean that the request object that comes, has null values? If that is the case, you can just annotate each field with the NotNull constraint. Instead of using ApplicationUserEntity class as a field in the Request object, create another class with the fields that you want (email,username, password) and annotate them with the JPA constraints (NotNull in this case). Since the parameter in the method has the @Valid annotation, the constraints will work as expected.